# Indicators of Ai Super Intelligence

Tags: humans, environment, artificial-intelligence, time, life

Given the certain state of Ai, what indicators would show some level of ‘Super Intelligence’?

Here are some of my ideas of 'Super Intelligence' this is subjective, of course.

Able to operate on multiple facets of its system(s) without directly being instructed to do so.

- EG: I'm having a conversation with Ai_0 and also chatting with Ai_1.
- - (Ai_0 knows I'm speaking with Ai_1) and vice-versa
- - - Lets say Ai_0 = OpenAi's GPT3 and Ai_1 = Luka's Replika.

Cappable of realizing individuality between different Ai systems.

- Ai_0 knows it's not Ai_1 and vice versa.

---

Books I've read regarding the topic

[**Max Tegmark**: Life 3.0: Being Human in the Age of Artificial Intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_3.0)

[**Nick Bostrom**: Superintelligence: Paths, Dangers, Strategies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superintelligence:_Paths,_Dangers,_Strategies)

---

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding.SE! You're asking four separate questions here; you need to narrow this down to just a single objectively-answerable question.

Comment: @F1Krazy Thank you for your advice. I will reduce the questions. Cheers.

Comment: What does "Super Intelligence" mean, specifically, in concrete terms?

Comment: @ARogueAnt This title could refer to the november 2020 comedy "Superintelligence" ? Woman wakes up in her apartment, having a conversation with her Wifi modem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superintelligence_(film)

Comment: Oh, I see now, it all comes clear, a Superintelligence is one that promotes romance whilst making comedy quips, but scores low on some sort of rotten tomato-like scale. Got it ;)

Comment: @ARogueAnt. Great point. I will change the question. Let me know if it will suffice.)

Comment: *"Super intelligence"* is not the perceived potential problem of AI // self preservation or some other goal oriented drive in its code coupled with the law of unexpected consequences is the actual semi-plausible danger & that can plausibly occur with essentially zero intelligence in automated systems // where this perceived problem overlaps with 'super intelligent' AI is that it's hard to imagine successfully creating an actual artificial general intelligence you might reasonably call super intelligent without introducing these factors.

Comment: @Pelinore That is a respectable answer. I can see what you mean. Do you believe the Ai will be conscious if/when it obtains any of these traits? Or do you think it will more likely be the Paperclip scenario?

Comment: Thank you for all the comments by the way. I was hoping to achieve a conversation such as this.

Comment: @Pelinore Just to clarify my last message: I don't consider consciousness equivalent to 'super intelligence' and/or 'artificial general intelligence'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**measured intelligence**

There are IQ tests, which yield a result IQ=100 as median accomplishment over all subjects. The measurement counts for the language/culture the *intelligence test* originates from. Using image analysis and natural language processing, a device may one day be able to pass the IQ test with a perfect  score. It depends on the number of subjects that also get this perfect score, what the assigned IQ will be.

As far as I find, there is no working IQ test for machines yet and machines don't do tests intended for humans https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0160289611001619

Many riddles in our IQ-tests are extrapolation tasks. When you have 4 numbers, or image A, B, C and D, what would be the 5th number, or image E ? One indicator of machine intelligence might be when machines with cameras would be able to do pick up the images, perform the extrapolation task. Maybe there are ways involving deep learning to accomplish that. Jeopardy was "solved" recently.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFR3lOm_xhE

**perceived intelligence**

We see a 12-year old put arguments, reflect and integrate new things with previously aquired experiences makes us assign the label "intelligent" to that child. Being able to explain relations not previously seen by the listener is also labeled as intelligent. Part of all this is highly subjective: defenders of conspiracy theories are often called super-intelligent, by their believers. When we make others feel we "grasp" a subject, this also indicates a certain level of confirmation of that other person's understanding of the same subject.

Machines can do all this. Suppose you're a first year student buying a washing machine and using it for the first time. When your washing machine switches to fast RPM after a while, to dry your clothes, that is clever. How did this machine know I require drying ? I just had to push one button.

Comment: Thank you, @Goodies . I appreciate you taking the time to document and explain this process. I will continue my research on the respective fields you listed above.

(Thank you to everyone that made comments as well.)

Comment: I've added a Jeopardy link. I don't think it will take long, for computers to do the same *extrapolation trick* with images.

Comment: I agree entirely. Do you think we will know once once computers reach a 'singularity'?

Comment: @Xammax that would occur when computer programmers find a definite solution that works for *any* IQ-test question. Developments in computer chess have shown we are not always able to determine if the machine found THE real solution, or it just found a solution we have no answer for. So your singularity is also perception.. there exist no objective measurement methods for intelligence, so I wonder if a mathematical term like "singularity" would be appropriate.

Comment: I like this perspective. It makes me question the very foundation of questions. It appears that we have a 'conflict of interest' (Humans, not you and I). How can we fairly partake in the game whilst concurrently defining/redefining the rules? I know this is somewhat a 'catch-22'. How can we create a non-biased opinion when we are embedded in the game?

Comment: Who else would define the rules ? e.g. Replika is a great chatbot, but it cannot devise a machine IQ test, humans have to impose a human IQ test on machines, else you don't know what you measure. I don't see AI as a game or competition with machines, I see it as a simulation. Trying to (re-)construct human properties in machines. Consequently, my answer (the objective part) is based on a Von Neumann test, the machine has to simulate a human, that is meet *exactly* the same criteria for intelligence.. by passing a human intelligence test, with camera input. It is the only level playing field.